# What does stack size in a thread define in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, stack

I'm using C++ and Windows.h in my source code. I read the CreateThread API in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I still don't understand the essence of specifying stack size. By default it is 1 MB. But what will happen if I specify 32 bytes?

What does stack size in a thread define?

Please provide a thorough explanation and I'll appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: the page you linked has this: *For more information, see [Thread Stack Size](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686774(v=vs.85).aspx)*. Please read the documentation you yourself link to.

Comment: Probably asking for a 32 bytes stack is not even possible, the minimum size should be one memory page (normally 4 KB).

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but when using C++, you should call [_beginthreadex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb.aspx) instead of [CreateThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453.aspx). This is explicitly spelled out in the documentation.

Comment: There is a *very* easy to way to find out what happens.  Try it.

Comment: For reference, the documentation saying that you need to use _beginthreadex is out of date.  If you're using Vista or later and your Visual Studio version isn't *hopelessly* out of date, CreateThread will work just as well.  (Fortunately, since you often don't have the option!)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: You are referring to the (now gone) issue, that there was a memory leak when calling `CreateThread` to create a thread the uses the CRT. The documented issue (*"If a thread created using CreateThread calls the CRT, the CRT may terminate the process in low-memory conditions."*) is still true, as far as I know. At any rate, calling `_beginthreadex` is always safe, and doesn't impose any restrictions either.

Comment: @IInspectable: oh, the documentation *has* been corrected.  My mistake.  However, I think the out-of-memory issue only matters in an unusual edge case, i.e., if your program has to function properly under low-memory conditions, which is very difficult to do.  In particular, the advantage of `_beginthreadex` is that it will return an out of memory error rather than terminating the process, but most programs will fail anyway if `_beginthread` returns an error.  But I agree that if you're launching a thread yourself, there's no reason I know of *not* to use `_beginthreadex`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The stack is used to store local variables, pass parameters in function calls, store return addresses. A thread's stack has a fixed size which is determined when the thread is created. That is the value that you are referring too.

The stack size is determined when the thread is created since it needs to occupy contiguous address space. That means that the entire address space for the thread's stack has to be reserved at the point of creating the thread.

If the stack is too small then it can overflow. That's an error condition known as *stack overflow*, from which this website took its name. When you call a function some or all of the following happens:

- Parameters are pushed onto the stack.
- The return address is pushed onto the stack.
- A stack frame containing space for the function's local variables is created.

All of this consumes space from the stack. When the function in turn calls another function, more stack space is consumed. As the call stack goes deeper, more stack space is required.

The consequence therefore of setting the stack size too low is that you can exhaust the stack and overflow it. That is a terminal condition from which you cannot recover. Certainly 32 bytes (rounded up to one page which is 4096 bytes) is too small for almost all threads.

If you have a program with a lot of threads, and you know that the thread's don't need to reserve 1MB of stack size then there can be benefits to using a smaller stack size. Doing so can avoid exhausting the available process address space.

On the other hand you might have a program with a single thread that has deep call stacks that consume large amounts of stack space. In this scenario you might reserve more than the default 1MB.

However, unless you have strong reason to do otherwise, it is likely best to stick to the default stack size.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but in the second paragraph it looks like you are saying that you have to reserve the whole process address space, maybe you should reword that sentence. Also, it may be interesting to add some examples of situations where you may be interested to set a lower or higher value for the thread stack size.

Comment: Upvoted, I think it's an OK answer. The second paragraph looks OK. Additional info that it doesn't necessarily hold for future implementations would perhaps just be more confusing than clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

Stack size is just tradeoff between ability to create many threads and possibility of [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) in one of them.

The more stack size is, the less number of threads you can create and the less possibility of stack overflow is. You should worry about stack size only if you are going to create many threads (you will have to lower stack size but remember about stack overflow). Otherwise default value is suffice.

Answer (score 0):

> But what will happen if I specify 32 bytes?

I have not read the Windows documentation, but if Windows allows this (to specify only 32 bytes), you will most likely get a stack overflow. According to their documentation the value is rounded up to the page size in anycase, therefore in reality you stack size will be at least the size of a page. The created thread assumes that there exists enough "stack space" for it to use (for allocating automatic variables, storing function addresses etc), and allocates space according to it's needs. When there is not enough stack space, the stack allocator might use invalid memory, overriding memory used elsewhere.

> What does stack size in a thread define?

It defines how much memory will be allocated for use by that thread's stack.

There is a good description of what exactly a thread call stack is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)

Comment: To whom ever marked me down, please be so kind as to give a good reason. To understand what the size refers to, one first needs to know what the stack is. From this it becomes clear what the size refers to, not? What better explanation of what a stack is that that one?